# How do I make this random list print only even numbers

Tags: python, list, function, integer

I'm trying to make a program but it keeps doing something wrong. The program I'm trying to make is two functions. One that makes a random list(it returns it not prints it). The second function has to make that random list generate only even integers or numbers. (I'm in python 2 but python 3 might help too)
Here's my code:

```
def random_list():
 res = random.sample(range(0, 50), 6)
 print str(res)
 
random_list()
 
def even_numbers():
   if (2 / 2 == 0):
       print(2)
 
even_numbers()

#What am I doing wrong?
```

Comment: If you just want even numbers, use a step of 2 in your `range`

Comment: `2 / 2` is always  1 :)

Comment: If checking for parity you should be using `%`, the mod operator. Also of note: `/` will always return a float, so be careful when comparing that to an int.

Comment: Ok I did that but its not printing even numbers.

Comment: When I added 2 it made two odd numbers each time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the list of numbers from `random_list`:

```
import random


def random_list():
    res = random.sample(range(0, 50), 6)
    return res


def even_numbers(nums):
    for num in nums:
        if (num % 2 == 0):
            print(num)


my_numbers = random_list()
even_numbers(my_numbers)
```

Out:

```
48
36
22
```